# How to override objects/variables/methods of node_modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, bots

I am working with botbuilder module for chatbot.

In that module there is one file Prompt.js in which I want to override one object which can be used everywhere where that object is being used.

```
Prompts.defaultRetryPrompt = {
    text: "default_text",
    number: "default_number",
    confirm: "default_confirm",
    choice: "default_choice",
    time: "default_time",
    attachment: "default_file"
};
```

I want to override it something like:

```
Prompts.defaultRetryPrompt = {
    text: "my_text",
    number: "my_number",
    confirm: "my_confirm",
    choice: "my_choice",
    time: "my_time",
    attachment: "default_file",
    digits: "My_digits"
};
```

so wherever this object is being used I want to display my values, so how can I override this thing or I can display value as per my requirements?

Comment: To confirm, is your requirement to custom the prompt? As according the source code https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ipromptargs.html#retryprompt, the  `defaultRetryPrompt` is not used in what you want.

Comment: In my code sometimes due to improper input in choice I got "default_choice" in response, so I want to prevent that, it is my requirement.

Comment: @GaryLiu-MSFT: I have tried after modifying this object, it is being used here.